# minimax algorithm returning different value with alpha beta pruning

Tags: algorithm, chess, minimax, alpha-beta-pruning

I am writing Minimax algorithm for Chess.

I get different final result values for minimax with out alpha beta pruning and minimax with alpha beta pruning.

My pseudo code is below. Can anyone help me?

miniMax()

```
public int miniMax(int depth, Board b, boolean maxPlayer) {
    if(depth == 0)
        return evaluateBoard(b);
    if(maxPlayer) {
        int bestMoveVal = 0;  
        for( each Max player's moves) {
            // make a move on a temp board
            int eval = miniMax(depth - 1, tempBoard, false);
            bestMoveVal = Math.max(bestMoveVal, eval);
        }
        return bestMoveVal;
    }
    else {
        int bestMoveVal = 0; 
        for (each Min player's moves) {
            // make a move on a temp board. 
            int eval = miniMax(depth - 1, tempBoard, true);
            bestMoveVal = Math.max(bestMoveVal, eval);
        }
        return bestMoveVal;
    }
}
```

alphabeta()

```
public int alphabeta(int depth, Board b, int alpha, int beta, boolean maxPlayer) {
        if(depth == 0)
            return evaluateBoard(b);
        if(maxPlayer) {
            for(each max player's moves) {
                // make a move on a temp board
                int eval = alphabeta(depth - 1, temp, alpha, beta, false);
                alpha = Math.max(alpha, eval);
                if(beta <= alpha) //beta cut off;
                    break;
            }
            return alpha;
        }
        else {
            for(each of min's moves) {
                // make a move on a temp board
                int eval = alphabeta(depth - 1, temp, alpha, beta, false);
                beta = Math.min(beta, eval);
                if(beta <= alpha)
                    break; // alpha cut off;
            }
            return beta;
        }
    }
```

Board represents a the board. For every move, I make the move on a copy of the passed Board object and then pass this temporary Board onto to further calls.

evaluateBoard(Board b) takes in a Board and calculates a score based on the given Board scenario.

Comment: in minimax the min player should call the min function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An big problem in your code is that `alphabeta` is not recursive, as it should be. It calls `miniMax`.

The recursive calls in `alphabeta` should call `alphabeta`, otherwise it is fundamentally wrong. That is to say, the alpha-beta pruning is applied at each depth level, not only the top level.

In the `minMax` function you have `bestMoveVal = Math.max(bestMoveVal, eval);` for both the minimizing and maximizing player.